# Anyone has experience on using GetAppContainerNamedObjectPath?

Tags: c++, winapi, appcontainer

Recently I came across a Windows API called `GetAppContainerNamedObjectPath`. But I have no idea on how I can use it.

I found a msdn page for this api (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/securityappcontainer/nf-securityappcontainer-getappcontainernamedobjectpath). But it does not have a right example and remarks, parameters are written poorly.

I am getting `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER(87)` error at the end, which tells me something's wrong with the parameters that I put. Here's what I've tried.

```
#define TokenIsAppContainer 29
#define TokenAppContainerSid 31
#define TokenAppContainerNumber 32

typedef struct _TOKEN_APPCONTAINER_INFORMATION {
    PSID TokenAppContainer;
} TOKEN_APPCONTAINER_INFORMATION, *PTOKEN_APPCONTAINER_INFORMATION;

void GetAppContainerProcessInfo(CString & procName)
{
    DWORD dwSize = 0;
    DWORD dwResult;
    HANDLE hToken;
    PTOKEN_APPCONTAINER_INFORMATION pAppCoInfo; 
    WCHAR wcsDebug[1024] = {0,};
    WCHAR * pwSID = NULL;

    typedef BOOL (WINAPI *_LPGETAPPCONTAINERNAMEOBJECTPATH)(HANDLE, PSID, ULONG, LPWSTR, PULONG);

    static _LPGETAPPCONTAINERNAMEOBJECTPATH lpGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath = NULL;

    if (0 == lpGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath)
    {
        HMODULE hKernel32 = LoadLibraryExW(L"kernel32.dll", NULL, 0);
        if (hKernel32)
        {
            lpGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath = reinterpret_cast<_LPGETAPPCONTAINERNAMEOBJECTPATH>(GetProcAddress(hKernel32, "GetAppContainerNamedObjectPath"));
        }
    }

    if (lpGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath)
    {
        DWORD processId = (DWORD)_ttoi((LPCTSTR)procName);
        //HANDLE hProcess = GetProcessHandleByProcessName(procName);
        HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, processId);

        if(!OpenProcessToken(hProcess, TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken))
        {
            dwResult = GetLastError();
            swprintf_s( wcsDebug, _countof(wcsDebug), L"OpenProcessToken Error(%u) PID(%d)\n", dwResult, processId );
            AfxMessageBox(wcsDebug);
            return;
        }

        if (!GetTokenInformation(hToken, (TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS) TokenAppContainerSid, NULL, dwSize, &dwSize))
        {
            dwResult = GetLastError();
            if( dwResult != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER ) 
            {
                swprintf_s( wcsDebug, _countof(wcsDebug), L"GetTokenInformation Error %u\n", dwResult );
                AfxMessageBox(wcsDebug);
                return;
            }
        }

        pAppCoInfo = (PTOKEN_APPCONTAINER_INFORMATION) GlobalAlloc( GPTR, dwSize );

        if (!GetTokenInformation(hToken, (TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS) TokenAppContainerSid, pAppCoInfo, dwSize, &dwSize))
        {
            dwResult = GetLastError();
            swprintf_s( wcsDebug, _countof(wcsDebug), L"GetTokenInformation Error %u\n", dwResult );
            AfxMessageBox(wcsDebug);
            return;
        }

        WCHAR wcsNamedObjectPath[MAX_PATH];
        ULONG ulRetlen = 0;

        BOOL bRet = lpGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath(hToken, pAppCoInfo->TokenAppContainer, _countof(wcsNamedObjectPath), wcsNamedObjectPath, &ulRetlen );
        if (bRet)
        {
            swprintf_s( wcsDebug, _countof(wcsDebug), L"GetAppContainerNamedObjectPath Path(%s)\n", wcsNamedObjectPath );
            AfxMessageBox(wcsDebug);
        }
        else
        {
            dwResult = GetLastError();
            swprintf_s( wcsDebug, _countof(wcsDebug), L"GetAppContainerNamedObjectPath Error %u\n", dwResult );
            AfxMessageBox(wcsDebug);
        }

        if (pwSID)
            LocalFree(pwSID);

        CloseHandle(hToken)
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
    }
}
```

As a side-note, I have tried using `wchar_t *` and dynamically allocate the memory buffer by calling `GetAppContainerNamedObjectPath` twice. But still had no chance. Return length does not return a meaningful value.

Comment: I can reproduce this issue with the sample. The problem seems to be in the 1st parameter, and after I remove the 1st parameter of the api(set it to `NULL`), it works for me, I will consult this behavior with the related engineer.

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT *The problem seems to be in the 1st parameter* - no. problem with mix of 1 and 2 parameter - thay can not be both not 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you call `RtlGetLastNtStatus();` instead `GetLastError();` after `GetAppContainerNamedObjectPath` you will got

`STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER_MIX` - *An invalid combination of parameters was specified.*

this give you more info compare simply invalid parameter.

then look for function signature

```
BOOL
WINAPI
GetAppContainerNamedObjectPath(
    _In_opt_ HANDLE Token,
    _In_opt_ PSID AppContainerSid,
    _In_ ULONG ObjectPathLength,
    _Out_writes_opt_(ObjectPathLength) LPWSTR ObjectPath,
    _Out_ PULONG ReturnLength
    );
```

the *Token* and *AppContainerSid* declared with *In_opt* -- this mean that this parameters is optional, and you can pass 0 in place one of it. then ask your self - for what you query token for *TokenAppContainerSid* ? are system can not do this for you if you pass this token to api ? obvious can. so you not need do this yourself. really you need pass *Token* to api and in this case  *AppContainerSid* must be 0. or you can pass *AppContainerSid* to api and in this case *Token* must be 0. when both *AppContainerSid* and *Token* not zero - you and got `STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER_MIX`

also as side note - you not need open process with `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` if you need get it token. the `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` is enough

---

really api not do big magic. it return to you

**`AppContainerNamedObjects\<Sid>`**

path, where  string form of app container sid.(some like *S-1-15-2-...*)

Comment: Ah, I see. So I need to provide either the token or the sid, not both. Shame, I did not think to look over the function signature. I really should make a habit on it. Thanks for the help.